# Multiple target values for fraud detection

Tags: classification, data-analysis

I have a dataset which has multiple values in the target column. The problem I'm solving is a financial (loan) fraud detection problem where I am trying to identify perspective defaulters.
I haven't come across problems where the target column has multiple values. Normally, its zeroes and ones in the target column. Do I continue with normal procedures for predictions or do I convert values > 0 to 1 so that my multi-valued column becomes binary?.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand what the multiple values in your target column represent. Do they signify different types of fraud, different levels of risk, or something else?

If the multiple values in your target column represent different types of fraud or risk levels, you might consider simplifying the problem to a binary classification task.

If the multiple values in your target column represent distinct categories that you want to predict, then you would treat the problem as a multi-class classification task.